# opengl 3.1 textures not loading

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I've been trying to get texturing working under opengl 3.1 on an intel HD graphics 2000/3000 graphics card running on ubuntu 13.04. The issue i'm running into is textures either dont load and the basic triangle i'm trying to texture comes up black, or some color from the texture will get loaded but not the entire image. I get the same outcomes using a raw image file as the source or loading a jpeg with libjpeg.

My shaders are as follows:

#### Vertex shader

```
#version 130

in vec3 vert;
in vec2 vertTextCoord;

out vec2 fragTexCoord;

void main(){
    fragTexCoord = vertTextCoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(vert,1);

}
```

#### Fragment shader

```
#version 130

uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 fragTexCoord;

out vec4 finalColor;

void main() {

    finalColor = texture(tex, fragTexCoord);
}
```

code for creating the texture
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

```
imgdata image_data = loadRaw("texture.bmp", 256, 256);

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image_data.data);
```

and the render function

```
void display(void){
glClearColor( 1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

//load program to use
glUseProgram(shaderprogram);

GLint uniform = glGetUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "tex");
if(uniform == -1){
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("program uniform not found: tex"));
}

// bind the texture
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glUniform1i(uniform, 0);

//load vertex array to use
glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);

//draw triangle
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

//unbind for next pass
glBindVertexArray(0);
glUseProgram(0);

glfwSwapBuffers();
}
```

the geometry and texture coordinates

```
GLfloat data[] = {
//X   Y    Z     U    V
0.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f,      0.5f, 1.0f,
-0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f
};
```

VBO and VAO being setup

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertprog);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertprog, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(verttexprog);
glVertexAttribPointer(verttexprog, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), (const GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: How are you creating `cubeVAO`?

Comment: "some color from the texture will get loaded" leads me to think the texture coordinates are ill-defined - so sometimes you'll see just part of the texture (perhaps a single texel) stretched over the whole triangle.

Comment: also worth considering:  what opengl extensions are supported by the intel chipset?  I like [GLView](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/) for a quick and easy way to discover what level of compliance is supported

Comment: Does it always produce the same wrong result every time you run it, or does it produce different results each time you run it, even if you didn't change any code?

Comment: I think `texture2D` is deprecated and replaced by `texture` in newer OpenGL versions, maybe you could try changing that?

Comment: I've added the VBO and VAO initialization code. I was running into an earlier issue where the texture color was changing with each run without a recompile, that turned out to be an issue with how the image was being loaded and the arguments used on glTexImage2D

Comment: You probably don't want your texture coordinates normalized, change that `GL_TRUE` to `GL_FALSE` in `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown the code where you determine the value of `verttexprog`. From the code you have currently, I have to assume that `verttexprog` (this is a terrible variable name, by the way) is uninitialized.

You should initialize `verttexprog` to `glGetAttribLocation (program, "vertTextCoord");` after you link your program. Likewise, do not query uniform locations each frame, the only time they change is after you (re-)link a GLSL program.

---

Your texture is being loaded correctly, but your texture coordinates are not. If you want to see this in action, you can replace:

```
finalColor = texture(tex, fragTexCoord);
```

with:

```
finalColor = texture(tex, gl_FragCoord.st);
```

This is not the behavior you want, but it is a great way to show that your texture is loaded fine.